# Сортировка двумерного массива через указатели

Tags: c

Нужно написать программу на языке Си, сортирующую двумерный массив через указатели, начиная с [i][j] элемента.

Пример:
Пусть программа сортирует массив с элемента [0][2], тогда массив:
1 2 7 4
6 5 3 6
3 4 4 4
станет:
1 2 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 6 6 7

Comment: Ваш пример непоказателен. Что значит "начиная с [i][j] элемента"? Что такое вообще "сортирующую двумерный массив"? Как можно сортировать двумерный массив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главное - что указатель на `a[i][j]` можно заисать как `*(a+i)+j`. А дальше - можно использовать хоть `qsort`:

```
int a[ROWS][COLS];

int compint(const void* b, const void* c) {
    return *(const int*)b - *(const int*)c;
    }

int main() {
    for (int k = 0; k < ROWS; ++k)
        for (int l = 0; l < COLS; ++l)
            a[k][l] = rand() % 100;

    for (int k = 0; k < ROWS; ++k) {
        for (int l = 0; l < COLS; ++l)
            printf("%2d  ", a[k][l]);

        puts("");
        }

    puts("");
    int i = 0, j = 2;      // Ваши параметры
    qsort(*(a + i) + j, ROWS * (COLS - i) - j, sizeof(int), compint);

    for (int k = 0; k < ROWS; ++k) {
        for (int l = 0; l < COLS; ++l)
            printf("%2d  ", a[k][l]);

        puts("");
        }

    puts("");
    }
```

Вот тут результат работы - https://ideone.com/4IRq7z

Comment: Как реализовать qsort без использования int compint?

Comment: Это функция стандартной библиотеки...